# How do I get an AppBar action button to change state when receiving a push notification in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, notifications, state, provider, appbar

I want to display a red dot on the AppBar action button icon as soon as I receive a push from Firebase.  I have created a Stateful AppBar and I am using Provider and ChangeNotifier but its doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Consumer<EventsBloc>(builder: (ctx, bloc, child) {
  return Container(
    child: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      leading: widget.backButtonIcon != null
          ? widget.backButtonIcon
          : GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    child: CanaryIcons().menu,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  ),
                  onTap: widget.onPressedLeading) ??
              Container(),
      title: titleEmpty
          ? Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, top: 20),
              child: widget.title.isEmpty
                  ? Text('Canary')
                  : Text(widget.title),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            )
          : Text(widget.title, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      actions: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Stack(children: [
                  Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined),
                  _bloc.hasNotifications ?? false
                      ? _bloc.loadingState == ELoadingState.loading
                          ? Container()
                          : _redDot()
                      : Container()
                ])),
            onTap: widget.onPressedAction)
      ],
      bottom: widget.bottom,
      elevation: 2,
      brightness: _brightness(),
      backgroundColor: CanaryColors.darkBlue,
    ),
  );
});
}
```

What is the best way to get the Icon to have the _redDot() displaying as soon as the notification arrives.  I.e while the app is open, and without having to navigate to a different screen first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this 3 ways that I am aware of.

1. You can use `StreamController` to listen for incoming stream of notifications and update the UI.
2. You can also use `provider` package (which might be recommended by flutter) to update the change when you get the new notification as well.
3. You can use `ChangeNotifier` class.

All of these do the same thing, they help you manage the state of your application. So long as you can get the notification data, you can update anything in your app UI using these state solutions.

Comment: So @eyoeldefare as you can see I am using Provider, and ChangeNotifier.  But it doesn't work without navigating away from the screen.  Would you be able to give an example?

Comment: I feel like I should try use some sort of stream.  Not sure how though.